We need to move cell A100 below A54
We are freezing rows from A51 to A54 and I have selected cell A100.
 await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    sheet.freezePanes.freezeAt("A51:A54");
    await context.sync();
    await context.sync();
    sheet.getRange("A100:A100").select();
    await context.sync();

  });

Problem:
A100 cell is selected but not jump to the top-below of freeze rows. a cell is select and shown at the button.

Expected Result:
A100 needs to select and jump below the freeze rows (a54) in the sheet by using officejs apis


Based on your screenshots, it looks like you don't want to move A100. You just want to scroll the worksheet so that row 100 is the highest visible row below the frozen range. Is that correct?

i want to scroll top A100 in sheet.

There is no way to programmatically scroll in an Excel add-in.

VBA has a method Application.Goto(reference, scroll) Link @RickKirkham do we have such in officeJS?

@KishanVaishnani I'm sorry but there is nothing equivalent to that in Office.js.
